# OnActivityResult not getting called in Fragment from Activity

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-activity, kotlin, onactivityresult

My flow of activity is like this.

In `Fragment` A, it allow user to capture image, and the image will be displayed on `Activity B` for user to do some editing.

**Fragment A**

```
mImageListAdapter.mAddImageClickListener = object : ImageListAdapter.AddImageClickListener {
            override fun addImageClicked() {
                val options = arrayOf<CharSequence>("Take Photo", "Choose From Gallery", "Cancel")
                val builder = android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog.Builder(activity)
                builder.setTitle("Select Option")
                builder.setItems(options) { dialog, item ->
                    if (options[item] == "Take Photo") {
                        dialog.dismiss()
                        val intent = Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE)
                        startActivityForResult(intent, CAMERA_CAPTURE)
                    } 
                }
                builder.show()
            }
        }

override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: Intent?) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data)
        var bitmap: Bitmap? = null
        if (requestCode == CAMERA_CAPTURE && resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
            val extras = data?.extras
            if (extras != null) {
                bitmap = extras.get("data") as Bitmap
                val intent = Intent(activity, ActivityB::class.java)
                intent.putExtra("bitmap", bitmap)
                startActivityForResult(intent, 12)
            }
        } else if (requestCode == 12 && resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
            longToast("It get result from Activity B")
        } else {
            longToast("Nothing")
        }
    }
```

In Activity B,once the done button is clicked, the edited image suppose to be return to Fragment A, where I expect "`It get result from Activity B`" will be displayed, but **nothing get displayed**!

**Activity B**

```
doneBtn.setOnClickListener {
            image.buildDrawingCache()
            val bitmap = image.getDrawingCache()
            val resultIntent = Intent()
            resultIntent.putExtra("bitmap", bitmap)
            setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK, resultIntent)
            finish()
        }
```

Comment: Try to remove the line from all places intent.putExtra ("bitmap", bitmap) and see the logs longToast ("It get the result from Activity B"). 
If log message "It get the result from Activity B" will appear then the problem is that the bitmap parameter is too large for Bundle. 
Or
Try to log onActivityResult in your host fragment activity.

Comment: @SergeyBukarev you're right, I get the Toast now, but how to pass bitmap?

Comment: Pass it through a static variable or save bitmap to a file and pass file name from bundle. Bundle parameter has a size limit.

Comment: @SergeyBukarev let me try

Comment: Possible duplicate of [onActivityResult is not being called in Fragment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6147884/onactivityresult-is-not-being-called-in-fragment)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As one of the simplest options pass it through a static variable

In the Fragment A create a static field

```
    companion object {
        public var globalBitmap: Bitmap? = null
    }
```

and in Fragment A in `onActivityResult` method save bitmap to static variable like that

```
...
    if (requestCode == CAMERA_CAPTURE && resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
                val extras = data?.extras
                if (extras != null) {
                    globalBitmap = extras.get("data") as Bitmap

                    startActivityForResult(intent, 12)
                }
            }
...
```

In Activity B read result bitmap from Fragment A static variablelike that

```
FragmentA.globalBitmap
```

Answer (score 0):

See i tried it a quick and added a breakpoint, and received callback in fragment.

[image]use ***context***

```
 val builder = android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog.Builder(context)
```

instead of ***activity***

```
 val builder = android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog.Builder(activity)
```

Comment: can you explain how your answer helped ?

Comment: You are passing an activity as a reference of alertdialog, so dialog will run on FragmentActivity. and any result requested will be dispatched to the activity instead of where you requested from. using context is more friendly to startActivityForResult.  it dispatches result to calling context.

Comment: `OnActivityResult` not getting called is because the parameter bitmap is too large.

Comment: Have you tried captured an image and display it on next Activity, then call onActivityResult again ?

Comment: i think you are doing it in a wrong way. First, capture image, and once you get an URI back in onActivityResult, try opening it in another activity to display if you want so. otherwise, camera intent will already display and request to accept or deny for using captured image.

Comment: ya, the reason is because the bitmap parameter